# Why does my concurrent function exit prematurely in Go?

Tags: concurrency, go

I am looking through Go Bootcamp and am reading the Go Concurrency chapter right now. I have never used concurrency before in programming and don't understand the output of this program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
hello

Program exited.
```

Can someone explain why "world" is not printed twice like "hello"? And maybe elucidate the idea of using concurrency?

Note, Go Playground link [here](http://play.golang.org/p/9JvbtSuv5o).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Go program exits when main returns. In this case, your program is not waiting for the final "world" to be printed in another goroutine before exiting.

The following code ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FuioS3MyEQ)) will ensure main never exits allowing the other goroutine to finish.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
    select{}
}
```

As you may have noticed, this results in a deadlock because the program has no way to go forward. You may wish to add a channel or a sync.Waitgroup to ensure the program exits cleanly immediately after the other goroutine completes.

For example ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/RBP06YHIEP)):

```
func say(s string, ch chan<- bool) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

    if ch != nil {
        close(ch)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    go say("world", ch)
    say("hello", nil)
    // wait for a signal that the other goroutine is done
    <-ch
}
```